# Sybase add incrementing counter to a select statement

Tags: sql, sybase, counter, post-increment

It seems that a similar question has been asked an solutions exist for other DB products (especially MS-SQL) but they don't work for sybase so I'm asking this question.

I have a simple select statement and I'd like to get a column containing and incrementing counter along with the results.

eg:

```
counter  data1  data2
0        aa     AA
1        bb     BB
2        cc     CC
```

Is there a way to do this in a single statement as opposed to putting it into a temp table and running a cursor over it?

Comment: how many results in total (usually)?

Comment: Not many, around 100, definitely within an int :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need as well to create a temp table but you don't need any cursor, just do it like this:

```
select counter = identity(10), data1, data2 into #t1 from tablename

select * from #t1
drop table #t1
```

Comment: Nice - this is what I was looking for!!! Now is there any way to specify what number to start at?

Comment: @VictorParmar: You can always add an offset in the final SELECT, i.e. `SELECT counter + 10 AS counter, data1, ... FROM #t1`.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of Sybase you are using, you could also have a look at functions like [`NUMBER()`](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbreference_en11/number.html) or [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbreference_en11/functions-s-5208160.html).